# Return callback() vs callback()

Tags: callback, coffeescript

Is there a difference between callback() and return callback() in coffeescript. I've gotten different answers from different people. If there is a block of code after just a callback, the callback function gets called but does the rest of the script continues to run or just it does stops there?

```
if something
  callback null, 'yes'
else
  callback null, 'no'

// DOES THIS RUN?
if something else
  callback null, 'yes'
```

Comment: This looks like CoffeeScript rather than JavaScript. Is it meant to be?

Comment: Sorry, yes the code above is in CoffeeScript and not JavaScript

Comment: I can see why I don't use CoffeeScript.

Comment: Why? It makes writing javascript a lot more straightforward. Obv, the above was an horrible example to get my point across but I prefer writing CoffeeScript over JavaScript anyday.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: You don't use CoffeeScript because it allows you to omit parens around conditions and argument lists? Because otherwise this is valid JavaScript with nearly identical semantics. It's really a very nice language that can improve readability of well-written code and helps encourage you to do the right thing a lot of the time.

Comment: @Chuck: Well, I guess the answer would be yes. But then I suppose if I used it, its syntax would become natural to me eventually. So if there are no arguments, would the function be called with a simple `callback` syntax?

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Nah, the parens are only optional for functions with arguments. Otherwise it would conflict with passing functions around (e.g. `doSomethingWithLoggingFunction console.log` should *not* call `console.log` with 0 arguments). The syntax looks a lot more natural if you're used to Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the rest continues to run, but with a `return`, you can prevent that.

Comment: Thanks thejh ... I figured as much.

Comment: @Olu The compiler has no way of knowing that calling `callback` is the last thing the function could do. There's nothing special about the word `callback` in the CoffeeScript language; it's just an identifier.